# Since/Until modifier time formats

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get posts for a given date/time range.  If I use yyyy-mm-dd it works fine, but I can't make ISO8601 work.  Should it?  I see documentation saying that 8601 works for event times, but can't find anything definitive on formats of since/until modifiers.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/#timepaging says, _“until [/since] : A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the end [/start] of the range of time-based data.”_ – so I think “strtotime data value” _should_ mean any time format that strtotime is able to recognize …

Comment: I agree and it works fine with yyyy-mm-dd, but it doesn't seem to work when I add the "Thh:mm:ss+0000".  Maybe it needs some kind of encoding?  I'll just convert to Unix timestamps.